# How can I determine the javascript that is deleting an element on a page?

Tags: javascript

I've got an html page that, after a certain amount of time, has a particular element being removed or deleted from the DOM.

The element is a div with the id "workspace".

There are *lots* of third party scripts being loaded in the page, and after some time, the "workspace" element is being removed, but I'm not sure why.

How can I determine which javascript library is removing the "workspace" element?

Comment: Insert `console.log` statements everywhere.

Comment: Try using firebug or chrome developer tools. You can do a step by step debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using chrome, you can go to the elements tab, right click on the element (before it is deleted) and click break on... -> subtree modifications. This should break the javascript right as this element is being altered.

Comment: This is the best way I know of to do this. Much better than using `console.log`, assuming you can add the breakpoint in time.

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome, and find the element in the "Elements" inspector.

- If you can see the element, right click on it, and choose "Inspect
  Element".
- If you can't see the element, Bring up the "Elements"
  inspector by selecting the following in the menu:

  **View | Developer | Developer Tools**

Right click on the element's name or node in the "Elements" inspector, and select the following in the pop up menu:

- **Break on | Node Removal**

Now the debugger will kick in when the item gets removed!

Comment: You couldn't have just edited my post? It's clear that I gave you the information you needed.

Comment: I was answering my own question, but submitted my question first, by mistake. If you'd like, I could totally edit your question, and delete my answer...

Comment: Yeah, I did.... I needed to know this yesterday, Googled it, and didn't see any results. A guy at work here told me how to do it.... So  I thought I'd post it on SO so it would be findable by someone else. So I went to ask and answer the question (which you can do in one step on SO) but I hit "Enter" by mistake and the question submitted. So I just hit "Answer" right off, submitted my answer, and you'd answered while I answered ;-) I left mine because I detailed the steps a bit more, but I have no problem editing your answer if you'd prefer! Thanks for answering!

Comment: No, if you meant to do it that way, it's fine. I love that stack overflow is so fast that a mistake like that can result in someone (me) sniping your answer.

Comment: Yeah.... I'll admit I was surprised that it was answered so quickly! and thanks again for the answer. I'll upvote yours, and leave mine here as well. Thanks!